# Flutter alphabetical list from a to z on right side

Tags: flutter, alphabetical

I want to implement an alphabetical list on the right side of the screen, i don't want to use a packages because they reorder my listview which i want to stay at same order, and i want to implement the onClick on a letter manualy.

So how do i implement this widget and make it stay on the side of the screen

[image]

Comment: give your appropriate code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do NOT quite get when you say,  "i don't want to use a packages because they reorder my listview which i want to stay at same order".

However, here is my implementation for your requirement.
https://github.com/thanikad/alphabetical_search.

The UI is arranged using Stack, ScrollablePositionedList,  and a Column. Used ScrollablePositionedList to enable the search against the ListView and then jump to the index based on the search letter selected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Siddique Thanikad !
The only problem is the indexing when I click on a letter. I expect when I click on Z and after on A to take me to results which start with A. I think is because the scrollController try to position the result in the middle of the screen and because A is on top of the list, it doesn't know how to deal with it. Is there a way to fix this issue? I mean when I tap on letter A, then the first item which start with A to be displayed on top of the list ( not in middle of the list like is at the moment).